# change image using javascript based on function result

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've been searching and trying to figure this out for hours but i seem to be missing something. Basically i'm trying to make it so if i click a link/button it executes a script to increase or decrease the number by a specified amount in a function. (in this example its by 1)

The image files that im trying to display are supposed to change depending on the final result. but the image never changes.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var p1hps = 20;
var p1hpimage

function p1p1Click() {
    p1hps = (p1hps +1);
    function p1health(){
    };
}

function p1health() {
    p1hpimage = "images/p1" + p1hps + ".png";
    document.getElementById('p1hp').src = p1health();
}
</script>




<body>
<a href="#" onclick="p1p1Click()"><img src="images/p1p1.png" width="165" height="87" alt=""></a>
<img src="images/p120.png" id="p1hp" width="324" height="252" alt="">
</body>
```

Comment: You're calling your p1health method incorrectly.
Try just `p1health();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the `p1health` function inside `p1p1Click`, instead you were declaring another function with the name `p1health` inside `p1p1Click`.

Also the images `src` property, you need to assign the value of the variable `p1hpimage` instead of recursively calling the `p1health` method

```
var p1hps = 20;
function p1p1Click() {
    p1hps++;
    p1health();
}
function p1health() {
    var p1hpimage = "images/p1" + p1hps + ".png";
    document.getElementById('p1hp').src = p1hpimage ;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YAgUG/) -- <sub>inspect the source with dev tools to see the src getting updated</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var _myPicArray =new Array("pic1.png","pic2.png","pic3.png");

function p1health(n) {
    document.getElementById('p1hp').src = myPicArray[n] ;
}
```